# is it possible to decrypt a hash made with ruby's bcrypt using js's bcrypt?

Tags: javascript, ruby, bcrypt

I have a database with data from old customers, as their passwords were saved using bcrypt to encrypt the passwords, is it possible to decrypt the passwords using a library in javascript using the same keys?

Comment: Bcrypt is a hashing function, there is no way to go back to plain password.

Comment: You can't "decrypt" a password hash from bcrypt. All you can do is check to see if a presented password hashes identically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake being made here is that you are confusing reversable encryption and decryption with hashing, which while technically is a form of encryption can't (or at least shouldn't) be able to be decrypted.

If you want to use the same set of passwords as are currently present then yes you should be able to just transfer the passwords accross and they should still match when users try to login, provided you are using the same hash function regardless of what implementation of the function you use.

If you *need* these passwords in plain text, i'm afraid your out of luck.

**Caveat**

It may be that your original hash function made use of a salt and/or a seed. Which you would need to know / be able to reference when matching passwords to ensure that the expected hash is returned.

Comment: `bcrypt` output contains the seed so that the bcrypt software an test a presented password against a saved hash. The whole point of APIs like that is to have the hashed passwords be implementation-neutral. But this answer is correct of course.

Answer (score 3):

**No**. Because you cannot "decrypt" a hash. **Hashing is a one-way function**.

You can go from egg --> omelette; you cannot go from omelette --> egg.

When a user submits a password, you don't *decrypt* your stored hash, instead you perform the same `bcrypt` operation on the user input and compare the hashes. If they're identical, you accept the authentication.

---

Would you get the *same hash* when using the `bcrypt` hashing algorithm on a given input, in different languages? (Ruby and JavaScript, or whatever)? **Yes**. But that doesn't mean you can *decrypt* the hash, in either language.

Answer (score 0):

Their passwords were not "saved", but **hashed**, you can't retrieve original data from a hash, that's the fundamental difference between hashing and encrypting.

If you want to know more about this, I recommend [this article](https://aboutssl.org/hashing-vs-encryption/)

---

The JS `bcrypt` and the Ruby one are the same algorithm, so you can still check password validity with JS code against your old customers DB.
BUT, you will have to remember the number of **rounds** that were used in order to obtain the same hash.

More info on the Wikipedia [bcrypt page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).